# C++ template-class Objects in vector

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, vector, interface

I tried to implement a generic Tableview for console-usage.

So i tried to make everything generic

- Templated class "Cell", which holds the data from one specific Cell
- template class "Column", which holds several "Cells" in a vector of their types (one Column one Type)

Now, I try to store the Column of all different types in a vector. Naturally this won't work. My next step was, that i tried to build a kind of abstract//interface class, which will be the base-class for the templated columns.

```
class IColum{
public:
    virtual ~IColum(){};

    virtual void setHeading(string head) =0;
    virtual void setData(vector<double*> data)=0;
    virtual void setData(vector<string *> data)=0;
    virtual void print(int n)=0;
    virtual vector<size_t> sort(bool mode) =0;
    virtual void reorder(vector<size_t> rf)=0;
};

template<typename T>
class Colum : public IColum{
public:
    Colum(){
        cout<<"TEST";
    };

    Colum(string n,vector<T*> data);
    Colum(string n,vector<T*> data, int f);

    void setHeading(string head);
    void setData(vector<T*> data);
    void print(int n);
    vector<size_t> sort(bool mode);
    void reorder(vector<size_t> rf);
    ~Colum(){};
private:
    string name;        
    vector<Cell<T>> rows; //templated cell-class
};

//Implementation of the functions
```

Later i want to have this:

```
IColum * colum1 = new Colum<string>();

vector<IColum*> colums;

colums.push_back(colum1);
```

`vector<IColum *> colums;`

Please, please can you help me?

Comment: What is the problem? Be more specific.

Comment: What is the issue with `vector<IColum *>`?  And what does `Cell` have anything to do with `vector<IColum* >`?  Or is it that your entire design has hit a roadblock?

Comment: The is no issue with `vector<IColum *>`, the main problem is: i cannot create a specific colum for e.g:  `IColum * colum1 = new Colum<string>();`

    `vector<ISpalte*> columns;`

    `columns.push_back(colum1);`

Comment: "I can't" and "it won't work" are not specific enough. You have to provide error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So. I found the solution.

The main problem was, that the interface contained specific methods 
`virtual void setData(vector<double*> data)=0;`
`virtual void setData(vector<string*> data)=0;`

In fact to be generic, this was antigeneric.. so i removed this.

```
Colum<string> * colum1 = new Colum<string>();
Colum<double> * colum2 = new Colum<double>();

vector<IColum*> colums;

colums.push_back(colum1);
colums.push_back(colum2);
```

Now it works.

Thanks for your time..

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution doesn't cover the case of using `setData` function from the vector. It looks like you have to create a generic data structure to have a such function available from a vector of pointers. Also, I'd suggest using shared or unique pointers (depending on your context) instead of plain C pointers.

Comment: You can also do dynamic casting when iterating in your vector if you want to use the implementation-specific `setData` function